# Issue with input fields forms in Phone Gap

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, cordova, textinput

I am using PhoneGap along with JQuery Mobile and HTML elements for implementing my project.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.5.0.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="target-densityDpi=device-dpi, width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> 
    <title>Meri Mrji</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/jmobile.min.css" />
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.mobile.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="signup" >
         <div class="contentwrap">
            <section>
            <div class="sectionhead">
                    <h1><strong>Sign Up</strong></h1>
                </div>
                <form class="forms" action="http://google.com" type="POST">
                    <h1>Please enter <strong>Your Details</strong></h1>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Full Name" />
                    <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" />
                    <input type="tel" placeholder="Mobile Number" />
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" />
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                    <p class="terms">
                    <a href="#signin" >View Terms</a>
                    <input type="button" value="Click me" class="green_btn" />
                    </p>
                </form>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Clicking and transition from one page to another and every other thing seems to work fine. But whenever I click on any text field to fill up the form the CSS seems to get distorted and zoomed in. Any one else facing same issue with Phone Gap or know other way out for it.

**------------EDIT------------**

At startup when App starts the resoltion of view port is some

```
 width : 500 ;
 height : 794;
```

after clicking in input field its

```
 width : 320 ;
 height : 268;
```

is there no way I can use some

```
 preventdefault() method
```

or if I can forcefully again change the viewport back to width:500 and height:794 ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally gotthe solution at some Random Url : http://uihacker.blogspot.in/2011/01/android-phonegap-scale-webview-to-fit.html

This is native code which seems to overrides everything from the **WEBVIEW** and giving it a consistent view with no zoom effect on clicking on any input value :)

Answer (score 0):

Removing **target-densityDpi=device-dpi** stops the zooming on my HTC Evo. More insight on viewports [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893045/making-sense-of-android-meta-viewport-scaling-what-am-i-missing).

Comment: but if i do that it doesnt show the layout same way and fluid like it seems to be in webkit browser when i check