# Viewport not sizing correctly on Android

Tags: android, viewport, meta

I got a weird problem with the viewport. On iPhone & Android landscape it looks great, but in Android portrait mode it looks horrible.

Here is my meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" 
      content="user-scalable=no; width=device-width; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
```

Images below:

[image: Samsung landscape]
[image: Samsung portrait]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893045/making-sense-of-android-meta-viewport-scaling-what-am-i-missing?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Try using commas instead of semicolons as delimiters. Also, I wouldn't bother with `target-densityDpi=device-dpi` as it's only supported in older Android browser versions and does more harm than good.

So, that would give you:

`<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width "/>`