# My static web site work responsive in locally. But when I host it in the server it does not work properly in mobiles

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

I am developing a static web site. First I made my site with mobile responsiveness. First I made my site locally using Google Chrome inspect Element. In their, I Choose Pixel 2 XL as device. Then I developed  the site and it worked fine in locally and still work fine in locally. After that I hosted my web site in the server. Then I looked my site using mobile browser. In their all the CSS codes I write for mobile responsiveness is not working. I tried so many solutions in the forum and neither of them not worked.

I tried using,

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=3, user-scalable=yes, minimal-ui">
```

for meta tag. But Did not worked. Here I use HTML and pure CSS.

P.S:

When I change my mobile view to desktop view in mobile browser it shows exactly what I create in local host and that's the right view. So how I change it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893045/making-sense-of-android-meta-viewport-scaling-what-am-i-missing?rq=1

Comment: No. But I just found out when I change my mobile view to desktop view  it shows exactly what I can see in localhost.

Comment: Could you post the URL of a page illustrating the problem? Or set up an example on say https://codepen.io ?

Comment: @DavidTaiaroa There's no reason that the OP can't post a [mcve] in their question using the snippets feature, or just the code itself. Linking to the site with the problem isn't allowed, nor is posting example only on third party sites.